# adding all the letters of a string up by 1

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

When I input `"abc"` I would like to get `"bcd"` as output.

So I want `A` to be `B` and `B` to be `C` and so on upto `Z` which will be `A`. 
So how would I go about doing this I have not the slightest clue.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to directly change a letter to a different letter:

```
try:
    from string import makestrans
except ImportError:
    maketrans = str.maketrans

from string import ascii_lowercase

#old = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
#new = 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA'

offset = 1

old_lower = ascii_lowercase
new_lower = old_lower[offset:] + old_lower[:offset]
old = old_lower + old_lower.upper()
new = new_lower + new_lower.upper()

# Create a translate table.
trans = maketrans(old, new)

# Translate your string using trans
print("abc".translate(trans))
# bcd
```

Comment: +1 This is the best answer.

Comment: +1 It is always better not to execute custom code in Python for every symbol if there is a way to use a standard library code that is implemented in C.

Comment: [`new = old[:1] + old[1:]` if only lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19690385/4279)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#ord) function to get the code point of the character and then increment it by 1, convert it back to the character with [`chr`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#chr) function. Finally, join all the characters with [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function, like this

```
data = "abc"
print("".join(chr(ord(char) + 1) for char in data))
# bcd
```

The special case of `z` can be handled like this

```
print("".join(chr(ord(char) + 1) if char != 'z' else 'a' for char in data))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using reduce:

```
astr = "abc"
print reduce(lambda r,x:r+chr(ord(x)+1),astr,"")
```

output:

```
bcd
```

EDIT:

For corner case:

```
 print reduce(lambda r,x:r+chr(ord(x)+1) if x != 'z' else r+'a',astr,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: code below only works in Python 2, in Python 3 the module is named `str` and `print` is a function.

Use `maketrans`. Following is for letters a-z only, not A-Z, left as exercise:

```
import string

lowercase_to = string.ascii_lowercase[1:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:1]  # bcdefg...xyza
translation = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lowercase_to)

s = "abc"
print s.translate(translation)  # Prints "bcd"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ord` function in python to get the codepoint of a character, and then `chr` to turn a codepoint back into a char. For ASCII characters, the codepoints of the letters are continuous and sequential in alphabetic order, so for instance `ord('a') + 1 == ord('b')`, etc. So you can do something like this (written our in long form for clarity, but it can easily be shortened with list comprehension):

```
newstring = ""
for c in "abc":
    codepoint = ord(c)
    next_codepoint = codepoint + 1
    newstring += chr(codepoint)
```

That's the basic case, but you will also need to handle wrapping from `'z'` to `'a'`, presumably. You may need to do some error handling in case a char is outside of the valid range. You can do that like this:

```
newstring = ""
for c in "abc":
    if c == 'z':
        newstring += 'a'
    elif c == 'Z':
        newstring += 'A'
    else:
        codepoint = ord(c)
        if (ord('a') <= codepoint <= ord('z')) or (ord('A') <= codepoint <= ord('Z')):
            next_codepoint = codepoint + 1
            newstring += chr(codepoint)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Character %r is outside of the valid range." % c)
```