# Reassigning letters in an alphet to a higher letter in python?

Tags: python

If I am building a basic encryption program in python that reassigns A to C and D to F and so on, what is a simple algorithm I could use to do this?
I have a list named alphabet that holds each letter, then a variable that takes in the user input to change to the encrypted version.

Comment: How are blank spaces and other punctuation marks like ', ',' and '.' handled

Comment: I want them to stay there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding all the letters of a string up by 1 python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481248/adding-all-the-letters-of-a-string-up-by-1-python)

Comment: @Simplex Please accept an answer from the answers below, if it solves your problem, this will encourage other users to answer your questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two major parts to this. First, ciphering a single letter; and second, applying that to the whole string. We'll start with the first one.

You said you had a list with the alphabet in it. Suppose, too, that we have a letter.

```
>>> letter = 'F'
```

If we want to replace that letter with the letter two spaces down in the alphabet, first we'll probably want to find the numerical value of that letter. To do that, use `index`:

```
>>> alphabet.index(letter)
5
```

Next, you can add the offset to it and access it in the list again:

```
>>> alphabet[alphabet.index(letter) + 2]
'H'
```

But wait, this won't work if we try doing a letter like `Z`, because when we add the index, we'll go off the end of the list and get an error. So we'll wrap the value around before getting the new letter:

```
>>> alphabet[(alphabet.index('Z') + 2) % len(alphabet)]
'B'
```

So now we know how to change a single letter. Python makes it easy to apply it to the whole string. First putting our single-letter version into a function:

```
>>> def cipher_letter(letter):
...     return alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + 2) % len(alphabet)]
...
```

We can use `map` to apply it over a sequence. Then we get an iterable of ciphered characters, which we can join back into a string.

```
>>> ''.join(map(cipher_letter, 'HELLOWORLD'))
'JGNNQYQTNF'
```

If you want to leave characters not in `alphabet` in place, add a test in `cipher_letter` to make sure that `letter in alphabet` first, and if not, just `return letter`. Voilà.

Answer (score 3):

[str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) should be the easiest way:

```
table = str.maketrans(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB"
)
s = "Test String"
print(s.translate(table))
```

Output:

```
Vguv Uvtkpi
```