# Subtract letters in Python

Tags: python, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract letters in Python, but I can't do it the proper way.

I know how to get the `ord` of the letter.

Like:

```
a = "a"
x = ord(a)   # -> this will give me 97.
```

When I try to subtract values from that letter I get a completely different result than what I wanted.

If I subtract `1` from `b` I get `97` (which represents `a`), but now I want to subtract `14` from `b`, and I want to reach `a`, then go back to `z` and continues the subtraction.

```
a = 97
b = 98
...
z = 122
```

I want to continue looping in the lower case alphabet, which is between `97` and `122`.

Example, If I subtract `14` from `b`, I get `84`, but in the way that I want to do it I wanted to get `n`.

```
b - 14 = a - 13 = z - 12 (...) and so on.
```

I hope you could understand what I meant to say.

;)

Can anyone help me here ?

Regards,
Ivan.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481248/adding-all-the-letters-of-a-string-up-by-1-python - one of those should be adaptable to solve your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would isolate just the lower case letters, then use slicing to your advantage. When you subtract past the beginning of the list, you will get a negative index, which will start indexing from the back of the list. This should give you the behavior you expect.

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> s.find('c')
2
>>> s[s.find('c') - 6]
'w'
```

Note that to make sure that `+` still works, you need to use the `%` operator in case you wrap around the list going forward.

```
>>> s.find('x')
23
>>> s[(s.find('x') + 5) % 26]
'c'
>>> s[(s.find('c') - 6) % 26]
'w'
```

Comment: I'would add: s[s.find('c') - 6%len(s)], if You are over 26 You'll get an index error

Comment: That's completely what I've wanted to do.... Didn't knew the % operator in python.